# Padding a 3-dimensional numpy array with the medians alongside specific axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, padding

Suppose I have the following numpy array arr:

```py
[[[  0   0]
  [  1  10]
  [  2  20]]

 [[  3  30]
  [  4  40]
  [  5  50]]

 [[  6  60]
  [  7  70]
  [  8  80]]

 [[  9  90]
  [ 10 100]
  [ 11 110]]

 [[ 12 120]
  [ 13 130]
  [ 14 140]]]
```

with shape `(5, 3, 2)`

Now, take note of the following dimensions of arr:

first `arr[:, :, 0]

```py
[[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]
 [12 13 14]]
```

with median `7`

and `arr[:, :, 1]

```py
[[  0  10  20]
 [ 30  40  50]
 [ 60  70  80]
 [ 90 100 110]
 [120 130 140]]
```

with median 70

I want to pad the first axis of `arr` with the pair of medians above (which can be computed as `np.median(a.reshape(-1, a.shape[-1]), axis=0)`), such that the result has shape `(k, 3, 2)`, for some k > 5, and is filled as bellow (as an example, for `k=2`, and final shape `(7, 3, 2)`

```py
[[[  0   0]
  [  1  10]
  [  2  20]]

 [[  3  30]
  [  4  40]
  [  5  50]]

 [[  6  60]
  [  7  70]
  [  8  80]]

 [[  9  90]
  [ 10 100]
  [ 11 110]]

 [[ 12 120]
  [ 13 130]
  [ 14 140]]

 [[ 7 70]
  [ 7 70]
  [ 7 70]]

 [[ 7 70]
  [ 7 70]
  [ 7 70]]]
```

Note that I can't use the `mode='median'` argument of `numpy.pad`, since it has no option of computing the medians considering only one axis of the array and flattening the others (If I fix some axis, it will always compute individual medians across each of the other axes).

The thing is, I used to be able to do this in a very simple way in numpy 2.16:

```py
md = np.median(a.reshape(-1, a.shape[-1]), axis=0)
arp = np.pad(a, ((0, k), (0, 0), (0, 0)), mode='constant', constant_values=(0, md))
```

But the same code breaks in numpy 2.19, with the following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (7,3,0)
```

Using `numpy.pad`, I tried plenty of input variations, with not luck. It is honestly driving me crazy, at this point I'm almost simply stacking repeats of the median array. But I'd really like to know if it is possible to solve this in numpy 2.19 using `numpy.pad`

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```py
# (reproducible setup)
a = np.arange(15).reshape(5,3,1)
a = np.concatenate((a, a*10), axis=-1)

# median along axes 0,1
md = np.median(a, axis=(0,1))

# "padding" with that median
k = 2
b = np.vstack((a, np.tile(md, (k, a.shape[1], 1))))
```

```py
>>> b
array([[[  0.,   0.],
        [  1.,  10.],
        [  2.,  20.]],

       [[  3.,  30.],
        [  4.,  40.],
        [  5.,  50.]],

       [[  6.,  60.],
        [  7.,  70.],
        [  8.,  80.]],

       [[  9.,  90.],
        [ 10., 100.],
        [ 11., 110.]],

       [[ 12., 120.],
        [ 13., 130.],
        [ 14., 140.]],

       [[  7.,  70.],
        [  7.,  70.],
        [  7.,  70.]],

       [[  7.,  70.],
        [  7.,  70.],
        [  7.,  70.]]])
```

**Edit**: If you want to use `pad`, then you can also do this:

```py
b = np.pad(
    a.reshape((-1, 2)),
    ((0,k*a.shape[1]), (0,0)),
    mode='median',
).reshape(np.add(a.shape, (k,0,0)))
```

That lets you use the `mode='median'` that you were looking for, in a way that is natural for `pad()`.

Comment: This works indeed, but It is not exactly what I'm looking for, since I wanted to know if it is possible to solve this problem using `numpy.pad` in numpy 2.19 (since I actually solved it in numpy 2.16). Still, I'm upvoting cause I missed the fact that it was possible to compute the medians alongside a list of axis as in `md = np.median(a, axis=(0,1))`, that is pretty interesting info!